# How can I get the path to the global npm_modules within javascript?

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

How can I get the path to the global npm_modules within javascript?

From command line, I can get the base path to the npm modules by calling this:

```
npm config get prefix
```

How, can I get this path within a javascript file?  Is there some module I can use to get this path?

I am trying to configure my protractor.config.js file to specify the paths for seleniumServerJar and chromeDriver, (which are installed globally), and I need to know the path to the global npm modules so I can specify these paths.

Answer (score 1):

There is an environment variable NODE_PATH
which is how node finds its node_modules dir

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is call the shell command from your script:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("npm config get prefix", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```